# What is this tool called?

Tags: tools

It's like a crowbar with a screwdriver handle.

I have found one called KM-569-A, but I need one for a job, and I have no idea what its called!

Image:

[image]

So, What is this called?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar tools are also available for automotive trim removal. They are often called "automotive trim removal tool" (go figure, eh...)

[image]

Comment: Major difference here is that the trim removers expect more space - tack pullers have near-knife edges and much smaller openings.

Answer (score 10):

That is a nail-puller or tack-puller (more commonly tack-puller with the screwdriver-type handle). You can get similar function from a "cats-paw"

[image: Cats-Paw] [image: tack-puller]

Answer (score 3):

The tool you want is called a "tack puller". A search in Google will show a plethora of styles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wiha makes a very small one it calls a "chip lifter":

[image: http://cdn3.volusion.com/ucbgd.syjxw/v/vspfiles/photos/26810-2.jpg?1408353660]